# Data in Postgresql dont save

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Ubuntu 16.04, Postgres 9.5, django==1.10.7

Data in my django project dont save in database.

I can fully use the application. But the data is not saved.

Migrate are working, createsuperuser too, but data dont saving. In the local dev all works good, but in production no.

In the postgresql-9.5-main.log was see this:

```
2017-06-16 18:26:42 MSK [1026-2] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2017-06-16 18:26:42 MSK [1026-3] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2017-06-16 18:26:42 MSK [1040-2] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2017-06-16 18:26:42 MSK [1037-1] LOG:  shutting down
2017-06-16 18:26:42 MSK [1037-2] LOG:  database system is shut down
2017-06-16 18:26:57 MSK [1056-1] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-06-16 18:26:42 MSK
2017-06-16 18:26:57 MSK [1056-2] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2017-06-16 18:26:57 MSK [1038-1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2017-06-16 18:26:57 MSK [1061-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2017-06-16 18:26:57 MSK [1273-1] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2017-06-16 21:35:42 MSK [5836-1] user@user LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2017-06-17 17:37:27 MSK [26684-1] user@user LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2017-06-17 17:37:27 MSK [26678-1] user@user LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2017-06-17 17:37:27 MSK [26676-1] user@user LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

Please, help me. I really need help. Independently I can understand. I read 5 pages in Google.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/62576). See [ask] and [mcve], and then come back and [edit] your post to add specifics that we can use, and to ask an actual, **specific** question.

Comment: Since you claim local dev works fine and only problem with the production, possible issue may be your production database `autocommit` mode turned off.

Comment: @IndikaRajapaksha, no, autocommit False, did not help me

Comment: Post the code where data is used and save.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts to find out the cause of the problem, the experiments with the reinstallation of postgresql and the date dump, and even the reinstallation of the operating system, with full application re-deploy, I found out the cause of this breakdown.

The whole problem was that my nginx config contained the following line:

```
proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;
```

It was the POST request that was cached by this directive:

```
proxy_cache_valid 200 302 1m;
```